# Pull the new branch on my computer

Tags: git, ubuntu, branch

I'm currently working on a "remote" project, i.e., I make programming on the server of someone. In fact, I'm starting doing programming in Django, and the team work use `git`. As It's been a while I've worked on that project, I would like to work on the updated branch. How do I make it available? I think I have to pull the master branch with the simple command `git pull origin master`, but it is unclear so far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all checkout to `master` branch if you are working on another branch

```
git checkout master
```

Then check if you have any uncommited changes by,

```
git status
```

If the above command shows you any files, then you have to stash your changes. If there are no file changes, don't do this step.

```
git stash
```

Then you have to get the latest updates from the origin

```
git pull --rebase
```

If you `stash` your changes, then you have to apply them back to `master` branch. (If you didn't run `git stash` command, don't do this step)

```
git stash apply
```

Now you have the latest version of the `master` branch & you are good to go

Comment: If I resume, I have to fetch, checkout the content of that branch and then pull with the command `git checkout BRANCHNAME`. Am I right?

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. If you are only working on master branch & you want the latest changes of the master branch to your local repository. Then `git pull --rebase` will take all the new commits to your local repository

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I want to work on the master branch & I want the latest changes of the master branch. Could you list what I have to do to do that

Comment: Updated the answer. If you have any questions about it, I can answer them in the comments